# Docker compose: remove container without interaction

Tags: docker

For a deployment pipeline I need to remove Docker container without user interaction.

When removing a Docker container using

```
$ docker compose rm myapp
```

`docker compose` wants a confirmation and only continues when `y` was entered.

How to tell `docker compose` to remove volumes continue without typing in something?

My Docker version is 20.10.21

Answer (score 1):

There's an option to do that:

```
Usage:  docker compose rm [OPTIONS] [SERVICE...]

Removes stopped service containers
[...]

Options:
  -f, --force     Don't ask to confirm removal
  -s, --stop      Stop the containers, if required, before removing
  -v, --volumes   Remove any anonymous volumes attached to containers
```

So the solution is

```
$ docker compose rm myapp -f
```